# Shell Script reading Enter key as an Input

Tags: bash, shell

I want to use the enter key as an input for a certain command.
But when there is no input I want to just loop.

If I write script like this then as the read command execution ends after 3 seconds with no input. it does not loop, but executes my desired output for enter key input command.
How can I fix this?

```
while true;
do 

read -s -t 3 -n 3 key
if [ "${key}" == $'\0A' ]; then 
    #do something


elif [ "$key" == ""]; then
    continue 
fi

done
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems, when using a *character-literal* in bash (it's bash-only), you need to use the actual-character, e.g.

```
    if [ "${key}" == $'\n' ]; then
```

Next the equality comparison with `[ ... ]` is `=` not `==` (though bash will accept the latter). However, you must have a `space` before the closing `]` in:

```
    elif [ "$key" = "" ]; then
```

Making those changes the loop will loop continually with a 3-second timeout waiting for 3-characters of input in the manner you want, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true;
do 
    echo "looping"
    read -s -t 3 -n 3 key
    if [ "${key}" == $'\n' ]; then 
        echo "enter key"
    elif [ "$key" = "" ]; then
        continue 
    else
        echo "key $key"
    fi

done
```

Give it a go and let me know if you have further questions.

**Edit Per Comment**

If you want to execute a function on timeout, then you need to check the **return** of `read`. When a timeout occurs, the return will be greater than or equal to `128`. If you then want to catch the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, use an else and then check for an empty key, that will show that enter alone was pressed. Otherwise, you hae 3-chars in `key`, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true;
do 
    echo "looping"
    read -s -t 3 -n 3 key
    if [ $? -ge 128 ]; then
        echo "timeout - execute function"
    else
        if [ "$key" = "" ]; then
            echo "enter key"
            continue 
        else
            echo "key $key"
        fi
    fi

done
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash test.sh
looping
timeout - execute function
looping
timeout - execute function
looping
enter key
looping
timeout - execute function
looping
key foo
looping
enter key
looping
```

If I have the timeout/empty reversed, just switch the logic. I'm still not 100% clear on your comment, but I think this is what you indicated.

Comment: I have tried your solution but when i put 
if [ "${key}" == $'\n' ]; then
it does not recognize my enter key input.
and if I put 
if [ "${key}" == $'\0A' ]; then
it recognizes the enter key but still when i have no input for $key it just executes what the enter key input supposes to do

Comment: I want to separate functions for read command execution ending with no input (after 3 seconds) and read command execution ending with enter key input.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to re-ask the input if the user did not input an enter, I'd suggest to change the `while true` to something like `while [[ "${key}" != $'\0A' ]]`. THis way you can re-ask the input until it's an enter, and run your command after the while.

Would look something like:

```sh
# Read first time
read -s -t 3 -n 3 key

# If this wasn't an enter, keep asking until it is
while [[ "${key}" != $'\0A' ]]; do
    read -s -t 3 -n 3 key
done

# Done
echo 'Running special command'
```